# password con buttons en java

Tags: java, netbeans

De momento puedo meter el password por teclado y chequearlo, pero quiero que en vez de meter el texto por teclado, se meta pulsando el boton correspondiente, es decir si pulso el el boton 1, que coga un 1 lo del pasword, pero que se vea con *

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class JPasswordFieldTutorial {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);
JButton button = new JButton("Perform check");
        JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
        JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
        JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
        JButton button7 = new JButton("7");
        JButton button8 = new JButton("8");
        JButton button9 = new JButton("9");
public JPasswordFieldTutorial() {
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
char [] input = passwordField.getPassword();
if(checkIfCorrect(input)) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password is correct!");
} else {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Password is incorrect!");
}
}
});
```

El password lo chequeo aqui.

```
private boolean checkIfCorrect(char [] input) {
boolean isCorrect = false;
char [] correctPass = {'1','2','3','4'};

if(input.length != correctPass.length) {
isCorrect = false;
} else {
isCorrect = Arrays.equals(input, correctPass);
}
Arrays.fill(correctPass,'0');
return isCorrect;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Alejandro te dejo mi sencilla implementacion, he intentado seguir tu logica y no cambiar todo sino matener el estilo de tu propio codigo.

Solucion:

```
public class JPasswordFieldTutorial {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);
    JButton button = new JButton("Perform check");
    JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
    JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
    JButton button7 = new JButton("7");
    JButton button8 = new JButton("8");
    JButton button9 = new JButton("9");

    public JPasswordFieldTutorial() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("my app");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 100);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        frame.add(passwordField);
        frame.add(button);

        frame.add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(new ButtonEvent());

        frame.add(button2);
        button2.addActionListener(new ButtonEvent());

        frame.add(button3);
        button3.addActionListener(new ButtonEvent());

        frame.add(button4);
        button4.addActionListener(new ButtonEvent());

        frame.add(button5);
        button5.addActionListener(new ButtonEvent());

        frame.add(button6);
        button6.addActionListener(new ButtonEvent());

        frame.add(button7);
        button7.addActionListener(new ButtonEvent());

        frame.add(button8);
        button8.addActionListener(new ButtonEvent());

        frame.add(button9);
        button9.addActionListener(new ButtonEvent());

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JPasswordFieldTutorial();
    }

    class ButtonEvent implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Object source = e.getSource();

            if (source == button1) {
                setValueFromJButtonToJPasswordField("1");

            }

            if (source == button2) {

                setValueFromJButtonToJPasswordField("2");
            }

            if (source == button3) {

                setValueFromJButtonToJPasswordField("3");
            }

            if (source == button4) {

                setValueFromJButtonToJPasswordField("4");
            }

            if (source == button5) {

                setValueFromJButtonToJPasswordField("5");
            }
            if (source == button6) {

                setValueFromJButtonToJPasswordField("6");
            }

            if (source == button7) {

                setValueFromJButtonToJPasswordField("7");
            }

            if (source == button8) {

                setValueFromJButtonToJPasswordField("8");
            }

            if (source == button9) {

                setValueFromJButtonToJPasswordField("9");
            }

        }

        private void setValueFromJButtonToJPasswordField(String value) {
            String currentPassword = String.valueOf(passwordField.getPassword());
            passwordField.setText(currentPassword + value);

            //only for debugging
            System.out.println(String.format("Getting the current password %s",
                    Arrays.toString(passwordField.getPassword())));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por el comentario, y una duda como hago para que me detecte si el password es el correcto?, si por ejemplo el password es 1234 como hago para chequearlo?

Comment: vale ya me salio, muchas gracias!!

Comment: @alejandro Deberías de reducir el código, está muy redundante. Por ejemplo, podrías usar arreglos.